# Deposit on registrar.forceRegister(who,deposit,id,genesisHead,validationCode)?

Tags: parachain, rococo, sudo

I'm trying to onboard several teams to the `Rococo-testnet` with the objective that they can then control the parachain. For that, I'm thinking of using the `SUDO` account and calling `registrar.forceRegister(who,deposit,id,genesisHead,validationCode)`, however I am not sure what `deposit` should be.

If there's another way of going around this, happy to discuss it as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After going around this for some time, I realized a couple of things that might be worth sharing.

TL;DR -> when using Root account, deposit can be *anything*, including 0.

- The [registrar code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/6d5578dbbbcf5f2e77b53ca2ed13a558c6ba13f0/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L238) clearly shows that deposit with this function can be anything.

```
/// Force the registration of a Para Id on the relay chain.
        ///
        /// This function must be called by a Root origin.
        ///
        /// The deposit taken can be specified for this registration. Any `ParaId` --> HERE
        /// can be registered, including sub-1000 IDs which are System Parachains.
        #[pallet::weight(<T as Config>::WeightInfo::force_register())]
        pub fn force_register(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            who: T::AccountId,
            deposit: BalanceOf<T>,
            id: ParaId,
            genesis_head: HeadData,
            validation_code: ValidationCode,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            ensure_root(origin)?;
            Self::do_register(who, Some(deposit), id, genesis_head, validation_code, false)
        }
```

- When looking at production commongood parachains like Statemint on Polkadot, you can see that the actual deposit stored on chain is 0, as querying `Registrrar.paras(1000)` throws the following:

```
{
  manager: 14GVkHxNBUV4BckMdwwVDVhJ9Xb6ckZDZZvE8eMc5MCfbd3x
  deposit: 0
  locked: true
}
```

Finally, I also tested it out and it seemed to work :)